# How to render the PDF page as EMF or meta file in PDFium

Tags: pdfium

Currently I have generated the PDF page as bitmap by using FPDF_RenderPageBitmap method.

is there any method for rendering the PDF page as EMF or as metafile in PDFium?

Answer (score 2):

In the pdfium project there is a sample folder that has a [pdfium_test.cc](https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/+/master/samples/pdfium_test.cc) file that has examples of output in different formats. PNG, EMF, BMP, TXT, and PPM are all in the at the present time.

The current code to render an EMF

```
void WriteEmf(FPDF_PAGE page, const char* pdf_name, int num) {
  int width = static_cast<int>(FPDF_GetPageWidth(page));
  int height = static_cast<int>(FPDF_GetPageHeight(page));

  char filename[256];
  snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s.%d.emf", pdf_name, num);

  HDC dc = CreateEnhMetaFileA(nullptr, filename, nullptr, nullptr);

  HRGN rgn = CreateRectRgn(0, 0, width, height);
  SelectClipRgn(dc, rgn);
  DeleteObject(rgn);

  SelectObject(dc, GetStockObject(NULL_PEN));
  SelectObject(dc, GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
  // If a PS_NULL pen is used, the dimensions of the rectangle are 1 pixel less.
  Rectangle(dc, 0, 0, width + 1, height + 1);

  FPDF_RenderPage(dc, page, 0, 0, width, height, 0,
                  FPDF_ANNOT | FPDF_PRINTING | FPDF_NO_CATCH);

  DeleteEnhMetaFile(CloseEnhMetaFile(dc));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you want to call `FPDF_RenderPage` and pass in the `HDC` this should allow you to get the EMF data out. You can see the chromium printing code for example usage. There is also `FPDF_SetPrintMode` which lets you set different modes.